# Calculating distance using latitude longitude coordinates in kilometers with Java

Tags: java, distance, latitude-longitude

I have following method that that calculates distance and returns it in miles:

```
public static int calcDistance(float latA, float longA, float latB, float longB) {

    double theDistance = (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latA)) *
            Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latB)) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latA)) *
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latB)) *
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longA - longB)));

    return new Double((Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(theDistance))) * 69.09).intValue();
}
```

### What needs to be changed in order for this method to return kilometers?

#### And what other ways of calculating the distance between A and B are there?

(preferably in java code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to change the last line to:

```
return new Double((Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(theDistance))) * 
    69.09*1.6093).intValue();
```

1 mile = 1.6093 kilometer

Comment: 1 mile = 1.609344 kilometer ;-)

Comment: For latitude maybe, but longitude distance is different based in latitude (it is not the same 1 degree at the equator than at the poles...)

Answer (score 2):

Since that formula returns a result in miles, just convert from miles to kilometers

```
kilometers = miles * 1.609344
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the haversine formula: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

The formula is multiplied by the radius of earth, which determines the resulting units.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to say

```
return new Double((Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(theDistance))) * 111.12).intValue();
```

equivalent to the conversions already expressed.

There are alternate and better formulae for calculating distances given latitude and longitude. [Lambert's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Lambert.27s_formulae) seems excellent, giving an accuracy of 10 meters over distances of thousands of kilometers, and uses some of the code you've already provided.

Answer (score 0):

The distance you are computing is based on Earth as a sphere, which may be good for comparing approximate --short-- distances.  For better results on longer distances (air travel, for example), I would recommend a Geospatial Utility library (such as the open source GeoTools) to take things into consideration like the Ellipsoid nature of the Earth's shape.

Many professional-grade Geo solutions use WGS-84 as the model, which GeoTools support.

Remember -- getting 100 decimal places of "accuracy" doesn't count if your assumptions are wrong! ;)