# Sorting in Jsp or business logic?

Tags: java, database, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Hello I have a Java EE application, I have a query which retrieves all the suppliers from suppliers table. 
And I have another table Location where I have the latitude and longitude of the suppliers.

Here is what the application currently does:

1. a servlet retrieves the list of all the suppliers from the db
2. sends them to a jsp  page- suppliers.jsp
3. it displays the suppliers details and their longitude and latitude. (using jstl)

Here is what I want to do.

In another table I have my current location.

Using the Haversine formula in the servlet I want to find the distance between my location and all the suppliers.

I am thinking of implementing this as a method in the servlet.
but I am having trouble:

1. how to make the list of supplier location iterate and be sent to my haversine formula method.
2. how to send the result to the jsp page.
3. how to display them in a sorted way, smallest distance first.

Answer (score 0):

`2. how to send the result to the jsp page.`

You can set your list in request's parameter and get that parameter in client side. After that you ca n iterate and display your data in the jsp.

`3. how to display them in a sorted way, smallest distance first.`
You should write comparator for supplier location. Through which you can sort your list. For Example,

```
    Comparator<Supplier> comp = new Comparator<Supplier>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Supplier o1, Supplier o2) {
            // your logic
            return 0;
        }
    };

Collections.sort(your supplier location list, comp);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: for the second part that fine, i got it through post paramater.

3rd part-could you please eleborate or send me a link to a tutorial. it will really help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your underlying database allows you to apply the haversine form (i.e. supports trigonometric formulae) as part of the query. Sorting and filtering are efficiently done by database. Populating a table is just a matter of passing the sorted list to your jstl. You can always sort the list using a custom comparator. I would rather do this using jsp custom tag.

Answer (score 0):

Plz refer the following link to get the formula for Calculating the Distance (in km or miles) 
[Calculating distance using latitude longitude coordinates in kilometers with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557706/calculating-distance-using-latitude-longitude-coordinates-in-kilometers-with-jav)

1.how to make the list of supplier location iterate and be sent to my haversine formula method.

Map dist;

```
 for (Supplier s : supplist) {
               dist.put(s, calcDist(s.getLatitude(), s.getLongitude(), currLat, currLong));
    }
```

2. how to send the result to the jsp page.
   Already your application does this as per your description.

3.how to display them in a sorted way, smallest distance first.

Write a custom comparator to sort based on the distance.

Answer (score 0):

you could put 2 methods in your Supplier class, one for setting the distance by giving coordinates and one for retrieving it; something like:

```
void setDistance(long latitude, long longitude) {
    // calcultate distance and set it
    //...
    this.distance = distance;
}

long getDistance() {
    return this.distance;
}
```

then after retrieving your suppliers, you could use a comparator to sort them; something like:

```
Collections.sort(suppliers, new Comparator<Supplier>(){
    public int compare(Supplier o1, Supplier o2) {
        return new Long(o1.getDistance()).compare(o2.getDistance());
    }
});
```

I haven't compiled this code; so it could contain some syntax errors, but it would do the job. You could even, in stead of an anonymous class, create a class like Comparator_distance, where you can set the coördinates to calculate the distance from, so you don't have to set the distance in the suppliers, but can calculate it while comparing. That feels a bit cleaner to me.

If you want paginated results, just make sure you sort before you paginate, otherwise you'll get incorrect results.