# Getting new GPS coordinates by adding metric distances

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I have been trying to find samples of codes in Java where I am able to add a metric distance to a particular coordinate point.

For example, by adding 2 kilometers to Point A's latitude, and subtracting 2 kilometers to Point B's longitude, I would want to obtain a new coordinate point (Point B) that is north west of Point A.

Are there any sample source codes for such a function out there?

Comment: [This other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557706/calculating-distance-using-latitude-longitude-coordinates-in-kilometers-with-jav) should help.

Comment: @assylias the post does not take into account that longitude "distance" depends of latitude. For this, and given distances short enough (maybe < 50 km), I would convert to Universal Traverse Mercator, add to the easting and northing, and convert back to whatever your sistem is.

Comment: Thanks @assylias but that's not really what I'm looking for...

Comment: @Sjuan76 hi, is the universal traverse Mercator the same as the answer as given below? Sorry I'm not really familiar with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need high accuracy and the distances are small you may assume the Earth is a sphere with approximately R = 6370 km radius. The difference in latitude in radians is then simply dNorth / R, the difference in longitude is dEast / R / cos(lat).

For higher accuracy you have to take into account that the shape of the Earth is more like an ellipsoid.

Comment: I don't need high accuracy as I just need the new coordinates to download maptiles from OSM, so it seems like your idea might work for mine.

Can I clarify what is DNorth and DEast?

So what do I have to do to add 2 kilometers to a latitude point?

Comment: dNorth is the distance in km in north direction, dEast is the distance in km in east direction

Comment: So to clarify:

new latitude = old latitude + (dNorth / R),

new longitude = old longitude + (dEast / R / cos(old latitude) )

?

for the longitude function is there an order for the division?

Comment: yes, with all angles measured in radians. new longitude = old longitude + ((dEast / R) / cos(old latitude) )

Comment: :( Seems like even for distances of 10km, it is already inaccurate

Comment: You can find more accurate formulas here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator

Comment: Thanks Henry, but there doesn't seems to be the formula that I want. Unless it is the y2lat(double aY) method?

Comment: It is. For longitude the site says: "The x co-ordinate is simply the longitude multiplied up by your chosen scale". Note that the results are accurate on a map with mercator projection but not in the real world. There is no way to map a sphere to a plane and preserve all lengths.

Comment: whats the difference between that forumla and the Mercator class?

Comment: I don't know which Mercator class you are referring to, probably there is no difference.

Comment: "The x co-ordinate is simply the longitude multiplied up by your chosen scale." I don't really understand this statement. So what do I have to do to convert longitude (the x-coordinate I presume in this case?) ? I"m not sure what they mean by the chosen scale

Comment: Look at the formulas for PHP, in those the x and y coordinate is measured in meters.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty confused by the website, even the formula from the java and PHP don't seem to match, and neither of them are giving me the right coordinates...

Answer (score 0):

I think so,You can do this using Great Circle algorithms.

The shortest distance (the geodesic) between two given points P1=(lat1, lon1) and P2=(lat2, lon2) on the surface of a sphere with radius R is the great circle distance. It can be calculated using the formula:

```
dist = arccos(sin(lat1) · sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) · cos(lat2) · cos(lon1 - lon2)) · R (1)
```

For example, the distance between the Statue of Liberty at (40.6892°, -74.0444°)=(0.7102 rad, -1.2923 rad) and the Eiffel Tower at (48.8583°, 2.2945°)=(0.8527 rad, 0.0400 rad) — assuming a spherical approximationa of the figure of the Earth with radius 6371 km — is:

```
dist = arccos(sin(0.7102) · sin(0.8527) + cos(0.7102) · cos(0.8527) · cos(-1.2923 - 0.0400)) · 6371 km
  = 5837 km
```

Another example i found out while exploring is ::

Example:

```
lat1: 34
lng1: 34
```

after adding 5km in lat1, new point should be like
    new_lat1: 34+5km
    new_lng1: 34 (lng1 will remain same as we only added in latitude)

So u can divide your prob in two steps ::

1. calculate coordinate using addition.
2. then calculating new coordinates using subtraction on one obtained in step1

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of confused from your solution. I'm looking to obtain a new coordinate point by adding metric distances to a coordinate, and not to find out the distance between the 2 points. How does the 2 steps you mentioned help me obtain that?

Comment: May be this link first post will help u...   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/SXBp528Eyt4/cB7fUaZ2GEgJ

Comment: Hmmm ok, seems like this requires some manipulation of the equation to calculation distance, noted. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Prateek, are there formulas out there that has already been manipulated? I'm not very familiar with the trigonometry stuff, I'm afraid that I might do it the wrong way! Also your equation seems to be quite different from the link that you gave me...

Comment: actually i explored and came to know about the above formula, as a way to calculate distance. Though in your case the link provided will be best.

Comment: Hmmm but the link mostly talks about distance calculation also? I'm a little unsure as of how to manipulate it to suit my problem...